# How do you refresh the whole page when I click on a tab on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several tabs on my page. When I click on a tab, I show some charts attached the divs in that tab. When I click on a tab, I need to refresh the page first and then execute scripts that will load under the tab. For example, I have this piece of script:

```
$("a[href=#tab22]").click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        load_chart1();
            load_chart2();
});
```

If I insert this line,

```
location.reload();
```

right befefore load_chart1() function call, the default page loads and I dont see see tab22 content, like chart1 and chart2.

Is there an easy way to do this?

when I click on tab22, the whole page should be refreshed and functions under tab22 should execute?

Comment: If you're using ajax to update a portion of your page, you'll want to prevent the default action of your click. Get the ajax response, and then call your functions. If you need an actual page refresh, you'll need a bit more work...The easiest approach would be a query string (or hash) that notifies your script an update is needed. Something like: http://yourdomain.com/page?refreshFromTab=1 (where your script looks for refreshFromTab)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to refresh the data via AJAX then you will have to update the the hash of the URL and check for its value when the page loads.

For example, in your document load handler:

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    curtab;

console.log(hash);

switch(hash) {
    case "tab-1":
        curtab = document.getElementById('tab-1');
        break;
    case "tab-2":
        curtab = document.getElementById('tab-2');
        break;
    case "tab-3":
        curtab = document.getElementById('tab-3');
        break;
    case "tab-4":
        curtab = document.getElementById('tab-4');
        break;
    default:
        curtab = document.getElementById('tab-1');
        break;
}

curtab.style.display = 'block';
curtab.innerHTML = "pasted from js";

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.reload();
});
```